# Go generate and go-bindata

Tags: go

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
.
├── client
│   └── index.html
├── cmd
│   └── projectd
│       ├── projectd
│       └── main.go
├── models.go
└── server.go
```

`cmd/gideond.go` produces the actual binary.

I want to run `go-bindata client/` so that I can embed the files in the client directory.

**Questions:**

1. Where should I put the go generate comment, keeping in mind that I need access to the assets in `server.go`. If I put it in `server.go` I have to run `go generate` in the root directory and not in `cmd/projectd`
2. Should I structure my code in another way?
3. How do I serve a HTML document and a javascript bundle using `go-bindata`?
4. Is it possible to source an embedded javascript file in a golang templates/html template?

Comment: if you need access to `server.go`, put it in `server.go` (or anywhere in that package). `projectd` is another package, so it's built separately.